# How to declare static variables in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Can someone tell how we can declare a static variable as part of a Objective C class? 
I wanted this to track the number of instances I am creating with this Class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use your class's `+initialize` method:

```
@implementation MyClass

static NSUInteger counter;

+(void)initialize {
    if (self == [MyClass class]) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}

@end
```

(Updated to add `if (self == [MyClass class])` conditional, as suggested in comments.)

Comment: Plus you might want to make sure that the `initialize` won’t run twice if the class is subclassed?

Comment: What's wrong with `static NSUInteger counter = 0;`?  No need for the `initialize` method when a standard C initialiser will work.

Comment: JeremyP - ha, good point! Had originally written with the static var being an NSString and the initialize calling alloc/init, then realised Krishnan only wanted a counter. :)